# Toggling circle on marker click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have some markers that are placed via an array of cords. Around these markers I have radius circles. I am trying to only display the circles when the associated marker is clicked and then hide when the infobox is closed. Right now the circles display regardless if the marker is clicked or not. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Could someone offer some insight as to what I am overlooking?

-Thanks

```
function initialize() {
   var locations = [
      ['Siren 1', 32.832, -96.629, 1],
      ['Siren 2', 32.827, -96.644, 2],
      ['Siren 3', 32.824, -96.612, 3],
      ['Siren 4', 32.809, -96.658, 4],
      ['Siren 5', 32.805, -96.634, 5],
      ['Siren 6', 32.809, -96.614, 6],
      ['Siren 7', 0, -0, 7],
      ['Siren 8', 0, -0, 8],
      ['Siren 9',  32.794, -96.613, 9],
      ['Siren 10', 32.776, -96.61, 10],
      ['Siren 11', 32.761, -96.633, 11],
      ['Siren 12', 32.764, -96.598, 12],
      ['Siren 13', 32.773, -96.581, 13],
      ['Siren 14', 32.748, -96.614, 14],
      ['Siren 15', 0, -0, 15],
      ['Siren 16', 32.751, -96.576, 16],
      ['Siren 17', 32.75,  -96.55, 17],
      ['Siren 18', 0, -0, 18],
      ['Siren 19', 32.728, -96.583, 19],
      ['Siren 20', 32.741, -96.566, 20],
      ['Siren 21', 32.738, -96.545, 21],
      ['Siren 22', 32.722, -96.537, 22],
      ['Siren 23', 32.708, -96.558, 23],
      ['Siren 24', 32.696, -96.499, 24],
      ['Siren 25', 32.694, -96.564, 25]
    ];

    var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.782878, -96.609862),

          panControl: false,
          zoom: 11,
          mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
    },
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
    mapOptions);

    function MyLogoControl(controlDiv) {
    controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';
    var logo = document.createElement('IMG');
    logo.src = 'images/watermark_MW_GMap.png';
    logo.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    controlDiv.appendChild(logo);

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(logo, 'click', function() {
        window.location = 'http://www.mesquiteweather.net';
    });
  }

   var logoControlDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
   var logoControl = new MyLogoControl(logoControlDiv);
   logoControlDiv.index = 0; // used for ordering
   map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(logoControlDiv);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    var image = 'http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png';

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon: image
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));

// Add circle overlay and bind to marker
    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        map: map,
        radius: 4828,    // metres
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
      });
         circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');

    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't see any code to display the circle when the marker is clicked.   The code posted creates the marker and the circle and displays the circle when it is created ({map: map} does that).

Comment: You don't see any code to display the circle when the marker is clicked because that is what I am having problem with.

Comment: I have tried a lot of different things. More than I can list and have done a lot of searching. I need to assign an click event to the circles that will display when its marker is clicked but, I am not having any success. Hence the reason I am asking for help. I am not sure what more information I can add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does what you describe: I understood you only want one circle showing at any given time. If that's not the case please comment and I will do my best to rectify.

**[Click here for the jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/4029/)**

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });

  var openCircle;  // declare the circle

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);

      if (openCircle !== undefined) {
        openCircle.setMap(null);
      }

      openCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
        map: map,
        radius: 4828,    // metres
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
      });

      openCircle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');

      google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow,'closeclick',function(){
        openCircle.setMap(null);
      }); 
    }
  })(marker, i));

  // remove what's below

  /*
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    radius: 4828,    // metres
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
  });

     circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
     */

}
```