# Toggle Markers hide/show on marker click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have done countless searches all which lead to how to hide a marker which is clicked on. What I am trying to do is when you click on a marker. The markers around it hide until the info box of the selected marker is closed. Then the other markers become visible again. Currently the only thing I have been able to accomplish is removing a marker which is clicked on which I not what I am wanting. Like I have said. I have done countless searches but have come up empty on find a way to hide other markers when a marker is clicked on then unhide them when the infobox of the clicked on marker is closed. Any suggestions?

Here is currently what I have that hides the selected marker which is not what I want.

```
      function initialize() {
   var locations = [
      ['Siren 1', 32.832, -96.629, 1],
      ['Siren 2', 32.827, -96.644, 2],
      ['Siren 3', 32.824, -96.612, 3],
      ['Siren 4', 32.809, -96.658, 4],
      ['Siren 5', 32.805, -96.634, 5],
      ['Siren 6', 32.809, -96.614, 6],
      ['Siren 7', 32.792, -96.656, 7],
      ['Siren 8', 32.785, -96.637, 8],
      ['Siren 9',  32.794, -96.613, 9],
      ['Siren 10', 32.776, -96.61, 10],
      ['Siren 11', 32.761, -96.633, 11],
      ['Siren 12', 32.764, -96.598, 12],
      ['Siren 13', 32.773, -96.581, 13],
      ['Siren 14', 32.748, -96.614, 14],
      ['Siren 15', 32.74, -96.592, 15],
      ['Siren 16', 32.751, -96.576, 16],
      ['Siren 17', 32.75,  -96.55, 17],
      ['Siren 18', 0, -0, 18],
      ['Siren 19', 32.728, -96.583, 19],
      ['Siren 20', 32.741, -96.566, 20],
      ['Siren 21', 32.738, -96.545, 21],
      ['Siren 22', 32.722, -96.537, 22],
      ['Siren 23', 32.708, -96.558, 23],
      ['Siren 24', 32.696, -96.499, 24],
      ['Siren 25', 32.694, -96.564, 25]
    ];

    var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.764980445475885, -96.60024896289065),

          panControl: false,
          zoom: 12,
          mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
    },
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
    mapOptions);

    function MyLogoControl(controlDiv) {
    controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';
    var logo = document.createElement('IMG');
    logo.src = 'images/watermark_MW_GMap.png';
    logo.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    controlDiv.appendChild(logo);

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(logo, 'click', function() {
        window.location = 'http://www.mesquiteweather.net';
    });
  }

   var logoControlDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
   var logoControl = new MyLogoControl(logoControlDiv);
   logoControlDiv.index = 0; // used for ordering
   map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(logoControlDiv);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    var image = 'http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png';

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        draggable: true
      });

      var openCircle;

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
          marker.setMap(null);

          if (openCircle !== undefined) {
            openCircle.setMap(null);
          }

          openCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: map,
            radius: 4828,    // metres
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
          });

          openCircle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');

          google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow,'closeclick',function(){
            openCircle.setMap(null);
          });
        }
      })(marker, i));

    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Toggling circle on marker click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23034706/toggling-circle-on-marker-click)

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate!!!!! This has nothing to do with toggling on or off circles. It has to do with hiding UNSELECTED MARKERS. Did you bother to read before you inserted your worthless conclusion that it was a duplicate. I am going to guess no. So explain to me how "Toggle Markers hide/show on marker click" is any where remotely close to "Toggling circle on marker click" That deals with circles. THIS deals with hiding unselected markers when another marker is selected. Get a clue!!!

Comment: @AntoJurković did you bother to read this problem first because they are two completely different issues and are NOT related. One has to do with toggling circles and this one has to do with hiding markers when another marker is selection TWO DIFFERENT questions. Maybe you need to read before you start throwing around assumptions.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is not duplicate: questions are different, code is the same.